# Symfony 2.8 app no style failed to load resources

Tags: php, css, symfony, bower, symfony-2.8

I'm working on a Symfony 2.8 app n the **Dev env** and everything loads except it is not styled. The Javascript & CSS files don't seem to load.

This is my **base.html.twig** file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>{% block meta_title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        <link href="{{ asset('public/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="{{ asset('public/bootstrap-table/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="{{ asset('public/components-font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="{{ asset('public/select2/select2.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="{{ asset('bundles/admin/css/select2-bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="{{ asset('bundles/admin/css/styles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="{{ asset('public/multiselect/css/multi-select.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    {% block stylesheets %}
    {% endblock %}
        <script src="{{ asset('public/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('public/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('public/bootstrap-table/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('public/bootstrap-table/dist/extensions/cookie/bootstrap-table-cookie.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('public/jquery.maskedinput/src/jquery.maskedinput.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('public/select2/select2.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('public/moment/min/moment.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('public/multiselect/js/jquery.multi-select.js') }}"></script>
    {% block top_javascripts %}
    {% endblock %}
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />
</head>
<body class='skin-blue sidebar-mini'>
    <noscript>
        <div class="global-site-notice noscript">
            <div class="notice-inner">
                <p>
                    <strong>JavaScript is disabled in your browser.</strong><br>
                    Please enable JavaScript settings in your browser to allow this website work correctly.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </noscript>
    <div class='wrapper'>
    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
     <footer class="navbar-fixed-bottom footer text-muted main-footer">
        &copy;&nbsp;{{ "now"|date("Y") }} TCX - All rights reserved &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;•&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Version-
         1.1.133
    </footer>
    </div>
    {% block bottom_javascripts %}
        <script src="{{ asset('public/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', { callback: 'fos.Router.setData' }) }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('bundles/admin/js/scripts.js') }}"></script>
    {% endblock %}

    <!-- form focus -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if($('form:first .has-error').length == 0) {
            $('form:first *:input[type!=hidden]:enabled:first').focus();
        }
    </script>
```

<-------------------------------------------->  **This is my Bower.JSON**:

```
</body>
</html> 
{
  "name": "NULL",
  "authors": [
    "NULL"
  ],
  "description": "",
  "main": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "homepage": "",
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "components-font-awesome": "^4.6.3",
    "jquery-slimscroll": "^1.3.8",
    "bootstrap-table": "^1.0.0",
    "bootstrap-fileinput": "^4.3.5",
    "jquery-timepicker-jt": "^1.11.0",
    "datepair.js": "^0.4.0",
    "jquery.maskedinput": "^1.4.*",
    "select2": "3.2",
    "moment": "2.17.1",
    "fullcalendar": "3.1.0",
    "fullcalendar-scheduler": "1.5.0",
    "multiselect": "0.9.12"
  }
}
```

The Javascript and CSS files needed are in this Bower.JSON file. So I ran `Bower Install` and all the packages installed into **`public/`**
However when I go to run the app `php app/console server:run` everything runs, with missing style.

Already tried clearing cache `php app/console cache:clear` & `php app/console assets:install web`. All help is much apprecaited!

[Picture of Error Log from Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBFNH.png)

Comment: Are you including those resources in your master (base.html.twig) twig template? They need to be referenced even after installing assets and running `bower`

Comment: If you are using AsseticBundle then you need to run `php app/console assets:install web --symlink` and then `php app/console assetic:dump`

Comment: Hi Jake, I don't believe I have a `base.html.twig` file. I have a `Twig` folder that was installed in Vendor > Twig. Is it essential to have one?

Comment: @LaurynasGerbutavicius just tried that, No luck :/

Comment: @JakeLitwicki I have found the base.html.twig file and everthing is included here

Comment: It'd be helpful if you shared your base.html.twig file (specifically what's before your <body> tag), because I'm not convinced those bower assets are referenced correctly there.

Comment: @JakeLitwicki jut added my base.html.twig file. Thanks for the help! new to symfony.

Comment: wtf you install into /bower_components and refference different files in /public ? makes no sense to me

Comment: Are you getting any 404 errors for your existing asset files? Those don't seem like they'd work as referenced there.

Comment: I get this problem yesterday and my workmate says to me : Just CTRL + F5. And it worked...

Comment: This might be a bunch of silly questions, but:
1) are your css/js files actually located where you tell your asset() function to find them? I.e.: is 'public/select2/select2.css' actually represented by the file '[yourRootFolder]/web/public/select2/select2.css'?
2) Is your `favicon.ico` loaded? And what is its actual physical path in your local document structure?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was having the bower components installed under **web/public**. Before they was installed under **public/**.

Important to note that if you are deploying an app with Symfony make sure that the requried packages are under the **web** folder.